# overloading operator== complaining of 'must take exactly one argument'

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the `operator==`, but the compiler is throwing the following error:

```
‘bool Rationalnumber::operator==(Rationalnumber, Rationalnumber)’ must take exactly one argument
```

My short piece of code is as follows:

```
bool Rationalnumber::operator==(Rationalnumber l, Rationalnumber r) {
  return l.numerator() * r.denominator() == l.denominator() * r.numerator();
}
```

Declaration:

```
bool operator==( Rationalnumber l, Rationalnumber r );
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it's throwing the error?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading. Since yours is a member, though, it already has the left side coming in implicitly through the hidden `this` argument.

Comment: You must define the member funtion with one argument or the file scope function with two arguments.

Comment: Is it a member function or a free standing function?

Comment: It's telling you, the member function must have only one argument. Makes sense, since you'll be comparing `this` and the argument. If it were a free function (as it should be), then it'll take two values to compare, so have two arguments.

Comment: is it a free function or a member function? Also, you should pass const Rationalnumber& instead of an object.

Comment: I think the `RationalNumber::operator==` part pretty clearly explains which one it is.

Comment: I see thanks guys. It is a member function, I will remove the class scope and try it now.

Comment: @chlong or leave it as a member function with a single parameter. In that case, it would make sense to make it `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: A non-member is a better option if the type supports implicit conversion. A member would allow `num == 0`, but not `0 == num` while a non-member would allow both.

Answer (score 22):

If `operator==` is a non static data member, is should take only one parameter, as the comparison will be to the implicit `this` parameter:

```
class Foo {
  bool operator==(const Foo& rhs) const { return true;}
};
```

If you want to use a free operator (i.e. not a member of a class), then you can specify two arguments:

```
class Bar { };
bool operator==(const Bar& lhs, const Bar& rhs) { return true;}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a ***member*** operator overload it should only take one argument, the other being `this`.

```
class Foo
{
    int a;

public:
    bool operator==(const Foo & foo);
};

//...

bool Foo::operator==(const Foo & foo)
{
    return a == foo.a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your operator== from a RationalNumber to somewhere else. 
As it is declared inside a class it is considered that 'this' is the first argument. From semantics it is seen that you offer 3 arguments to a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
friend bool operator==( Rationalnumber l, Rationalnumber r );
```

when you declare it as non-member function, it can take two arguments.
when you declare it as member function, it can only take one argument.