# operator== overloading considering non-static member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have defined a class like this

```
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  typedef std::pair< int, int > index;
  bool operator == ( const index &l, const index &r )
  {
    return (l.first == r.first && l.second == r.second);
  }
  void bar()
  {
    index i1;
    i1.first = 10;
    i1.second = 20;
    index i2;
    i2.first = 10;
    i2.second = 200;
    if (i1 == i2)
       cout << "equal\n";
  }
};
```

However I get this error in windows

```
error C2804: binary 'operator ==' has too many parameters
```

and this error in linux

```
operator==(const  std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)’ must take exactly one argument
```

I found this topic [overloading operator== complaining of 'must take exactly one argument'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229074/overloading-operator-complaining-of-must-take-exactly-one-argument) and seems to be a problem with static and non-static functions in a class. However I don't know how to apply `this`

For example, this is not correct

```
  bool operator == ( const index &r )
  {
    return (this->first == r.first && this->second == r.second);
  }
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Has std::pair not got an == operator already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator==` can be implemented in two ways:

- As member function: in this case, the function takes one argument and is invoked on the left operand which is passed as `this` pointer implicitly to the function.
- As non-member function, in which case, the  function takes two arguments, left and right operands.

Since you're implementing `operator==` for `std::pair`, you cannot implement it as member function (of `std::pair`).   The option you're left with is non-member function.

So implement it outside the class as:

```
bool operator==(std::pair<int,int> const & l, std::pair<int,int> const & r)
{
    return (l.first == r.first && l.second == r.second);
}
```

**But then you don't really need to implement it yourself unless you want to implement it differently.** The Standard Library has already provided a [generic version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) of `operator==` for `std::pair` which lexicographically compares the values in the pair, like I did above, i.e compare `first` with `first` and `second` with `second`. If you need to compare them differently, only then provide your own specific definition (non-template version).

The above mentioned points are worth noting as to how to implement `operator==` when you need it for your defined types.

Comment: Please don't do this though.  `std::pair` already has a generic `operator==` overload that does the sensible thing (compares first against first, and second against second).  Just create your own struct that holds two ints, not as a typedef of `std::pair<int,int>`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes. I wrote that.

Comment: @Nawaz: My comment was for the OP though.  Notice that the standard library version will *not* work for his case, since he compares lhs.first against rhs.second, and completely ignores rhs.first.  That's why I recommended creating his own struct.  Unless that was a typo.

Comment: No that was a typo. first with first, second with second. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I notice that now, and I think that is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move `operator==` out of class foo:

```
bool operator == ( const foo::index &l, const foo::index &r )
{
  return (l.first == r.second && l.second == r.second);
}

class foo {
public:
   typedef std::pair< int, int > index;
  void bar()
  {
    index i1;
    i1.first = 10;
    i1.second = 20;
    index i2;
    i2.first = 10;
    i2.second = 200;
    if (i1 == i2)
       cout << "equal\n";
  }
};
```

Also note, `std::pair` has overload `operator==` already, see: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), you might reconsider if necessary to write your own again.

Comment: Obviously, you are changing the name of index there. Why not leave the typedef where it is, and qualify the names in the function?

Answer (score 2):

If you overload the `==` operator inside a class, it should only take a single parameter so that comparison can be done between the current object and the argument.

Comment: So what does the `return` statement look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can move that operator out of the class, that way you can take 2 operands. Indeed there is no point of keeping it within the class at this point, since you are only comparing member variables and not the class itself.

Indeed I wont be surprised if `pair` already defines the operator you write.

Edit : Yup It looks like [`pair` already implements this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/)

> Two pair objects are compared equal if the first elements in both objects compare equal to each other and both second elements also compare equal to each other - they all have to match.

p.s. I think you meant

```
return (l.first == r.first && l.second == r.second);
                    ^^^^^^
```